# How to get URL for Go button in Tab Homepage

Tags: visualforce, community, custom-button, dynamic-visualforce

Hi i am using custom vf page for Tab Homepage. I need Go button that redirecting to standard list view page. what is the url for redirecting to list view page.
[image]

Comment: how are you constructing the tab home page in your VF ? can you share your current VF page code for the above screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

if you run the view, you'll be able to use the URL that is there.  For example, here is a List View link on Lead in my org.

...salesforce.com/00Q?**fcf**=00BU0000003I3wF

The **fcf** parameter is the Id of the view.